# Handling 2 compiler errors translating C# to F#

Tags: c#, f#

I am having some trouble porting this code to f#

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm ()
    {
        Text = "My Cross-Platform App";
        Size = new Size (200, 200);
        Content = new Label { Text = "Hello World!" };
    }

    [STAThread]
    static void Main () {
        var app = new Application();
        app.Initialized += delegate {
            app.MainForm = new MyForm ();
            app.MainForm.Show ();
        };
        app.Run ();
    }
}
```

---

```
open System
open Eto.Forms
open Eto.Drawing

type MyWindow()=
    inherit Form()
    override this.Size = Size(500,500)
    override this.Text = "test" // no abstract property was found
    override this.Content = new Label() // no abstract property was found

[<STAThread>]
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let app = new Application()
    app.Initialized.Add( fun e -> app.MainForm <- new Form()
                                  app.MainForm.Show())
    app.Run()
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

I have a few problems:

1.) How do I access members from the base class?

```
{
    Text = "My Cross-Platform App";
    Size = new Size (200, 200);
    Content = new Label { Text = "Hello World!" };
}
```

I tried it with override, but it only works for Size and not for Content and Text.

2.) How do I translate this line to f# `Content = new Label { Text = "Hello World!" };`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So a quick fix

```
type MyWindow()=
    inherit Form()
    override this.Size = Size(500,500)
    override this.Text = "test" // no abstract property was found
    override this.Content = new Label() // no abstract property was found
```

should be

```
type MyWindow() as this =
    inherit Form()
    do this.Size <- Size(500,500)
    do this.Text <- "test" 
    do this.Content <- new Label()
```

finally,

```
Content = new Label { Text = "Hello World!" }
```

is

```
let Content = new Label(Text = "Hello World!")
```

Comment: Instead of repeating `do` three times, you can indent the three assignments one level deeper, starting on the line after `do` all by itself.